# CSS : How to give different spacers within the same navigation menu

Tags: html, css

Sorry if the title does not explain exactly what i mean, what im looking for a hand with is the website im currently working on uses line-height:80px which is what i want, but if i add a drop down menu on a link, the drop down also has the line height 80px, is there a way to give this a separate height, im sure this is simple but having one of those days where i can no figure this out, here is the code for both html and css.

HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="about.html">About US</a>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <a href="product.html">Our Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="blog.html">Social Media</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    *width: 345px; 
}
#navigation li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position:relative;
}
#navigation li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#navigation li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Oswald";
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#navigation li a:hover, #navigation li.selected a {
    color: #ffc947;
}  

#navigation a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
#navigation ul{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
}
#navigation ul li{
    padding-top:1px;
    float:none;
}
#navigation ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; 
}
#navigation li:hover ul{ 
    left:0; 
}
#navigation li:hover a{ 
    background:#;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#navigation li:hover ul a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navigation li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
    background:#;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! You just need to specify a different line height for lists within other list items in the navigation.  Something like this, for example:

```
#navigation li ul { 
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CaseyRule/6osazsfa/

Comment: Yup perfect, thank you ! will accept answer as soon as it lets me...8mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
#navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    *width: 345px; 
}
#navigation li {
    line-height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position:relative;
}
#navigation li ul li {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also change '#navigation li' to '#navigation > li'.
this will modify only the first level of child li and not the ones inside the other ul.